# static_assert failed because value type is destructible for std::vector

Tags: c++, c++14, stdvector

I have a very simple program. Not sure why `static_assert(is_destructible<_Value_type>::value` fails.

```
<source>:16:12:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.1.0/include/c++/8.1.0/bits/stl_construct.h:133:21: error: static assertion failed: value type is destructible
       static_assert(is_destructible<_Value_type>::value,
```

Here is the implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class MovieData {
    MovieData(){}
    ~MovieData(){}
};

typedef vector<MovieData> Movies;

int main()
{   
    
    Movies result; // Line 16
    return 0;
}
```

If destructor is commented `// ~MovieData(){}` the program compiles. Can some once explain why my destructor is causing an issue?

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with `std::vector`.  Try this: `int main() { MovieData m; }` -- you will [get an error there also](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48ee726a9f1864e0).  You probably would have gotten a more meaningful error message if you tried that code.

Comment: Additional note: `=default` syntax is preferred over an empty constructor/destructor.

Comment: The error message is somewhat confusing. The static assert expresses the requirement that "value type is destructible", that is, when you create a `vector<T>`, `T` must be destructible. The error message is saying that this assert failed. So the problem it's reporting (rightly or wrongly) is that the value type is not destructible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> static_assert failed because value type is destructible for std::vector

No, the assert fails because the value type is **not** destructible.

> Can some once explain why destructor is causing an issue ?

If you declare a private destructor, then the class is not destructible (outside of the member functions of the class). Don't declare a private destructor if you want to store instances of the class in a vector.

> If destructor is commented // ~MovieData(){} the program compiles.

This is a good way to fix the program.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your class destructor is `private` (as are all *declared* class members, by default). Add the `public:` line and you should have no problem:

```cpp
class MovieData {
public:
    MovieData(){}
    ~MovieData(){}
};
```

Comment: I ran into a similar issue with a derived class. I fixed it by making the base class destructure public virtual